# Let table width surpass page width dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a table with a dynamically generated number of s in each row. I want the tables width to surpass the width of the page, to keep each of the s innerHTMLs to stay on a single line - to keep the table looking clean. Currently, the tables s expand to contain the text within them, to prevent text from wrapping, only until the tables width reaches the pages width, at which point some of the text within the s will wrap, making the table look untidy and inconsistent.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have some code for us to edit / look at?

Comment: hard to say without seeing your code

Comment: The table is completely unstyled, and placed within the body, on its own. I can't really share the page as it's for a private job within my workplace (it contains lots of private customer information). Still, here's a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/j2x94/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j2x94/1/ does this help

Comment: Thank you pravin! white-space: nowrap; was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
table {
    min-width: /*width of table*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a "tableless" option? It should give you the flexibility that you want.

Here's a link showing how to do it:
http://chrismaxwell.com/tableless/grid.html

This blogger even came up with a crazy approach involving images:
http://chrismaxwell.com/tableless/grid_liquid.html

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to the stylesheet, or individual elements style object, it will prevent text from wrapping, letting the tables width surpass the pages width.

```
td
{
white-space: nowrap;
}
```